# Which TensorFlow version is compatible with NumPy version==1.18?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, librosa

I need to use the `librosa` and `tensorflow` packages for a Neural Network audio classification project.

`librosa` has a dependency on the `numba` package, which requires `numpy` version==1.18.

But, `tensorflow` requires `numpy` version==1.2.

Can I install both versions of `numpy` simultaneously?
If not, which version should I downgrade `tensorflow` to, for achieving compatibility with `numpy` version==1.18?

Comment: I'd be surprised if `numba` explicitly depends on `numpy==1.18`, or if `tensorflow` specifically requires `numpy==1.2`. What makes you think they do?

Comment: Yeah, [`numba` depends on some minimum version of `numpy`](https://github.com/numba/numba/blob/87ab859d95aa6322a72d3d31027f39a6ddf4af10/setup.py#L362), not a specific version. [Ditto TensorFlow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/871d5a2e5bf37ddca8f023513a43f86b2be05756/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/setup.py#L87).

Answer (score 0):

You can install **TensorFlow 2.7** which supports **numpy>=1.14.5** and is compatible with the latest versions of **librosa**.

```
!pip install tensorflow==2.7
```